# mysql insert record before last

Tags: php, mysql, record

I have a small problem
I have a database with the following records

```
 tag
 ---
 a
 b
 c
 eof
```

eof must always be the last record

how can I insert a field before
EOF to avoid this situation?

if i delete eof and insert a field and 
after insert eof, i found this strange
situation, mysql writes eof before ??

```
 tag
 ---
 a
 b
 c
 eof
 d
```

I tried it with order by but does not work
I read the record positionally

thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your table structure.

describe db_name in mysql command pormpt.

etc: indexes, primary keys and so on

Comment: CREATE TABLE tsynapse 
     (
       id INT  AUTO_INCREMENT,
       tag    TEXT ,
       token   TEXT ,
       rule   TEXT ,
       trans  TEXT , 
       PRIMARY KEY (id)
       ) ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: delete from tsynapse where tag='eof' ;

Comment: INSERT INTO tsynapse ( tag , token , rule , trans  ) VALUES
(
"draw_image" ,
"disegna^99 immagine^99 $1  {current_surface}" ,
""   ,
"draw_image ( $1 );" 
) ;


/* ********************************************************** EOF ; */

INSERT INTO tsynapse ( tag , token , rule , trans  ) VALUES
(

"eof" ,
"eof" ,
""   ,
" /* eof */ ;" 
) ;

Answer (score 4):

This will return `eof` always last

```
select * from tsynapse 
order by case when tag = 'eof' 
              then 2 
              else 1 
         end asc, tag asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an aditional field my friend, which will be your index

```
UPDATE tablename SET position = CASE 
WHEN position >= $position THEN position+1 
ELSE position END
```

Where $position is the MAX() of the position column, then you can insert your new entry instead of the old MAX().

If you need further help, just let me know